# Adding iPhone 6/iPhone 6 Plus icons without Asset Catalog still keeping the Zoom Mode

Tags: ios, ios8, asset-catalog, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I want my app to have a new icon for iPhone 6/iPhone 6 plus BUT I don't want to use the Asset Catalog and I still want the app to open in Zoom/Scale mode (I don't want to make any changes and for it to look good on the new iPhones).

What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

just put new icon files Icon-Small@3x.png (87x87), Icon-Small-40@3x.png (120x120), Icon-60@3x.png (180x180). To keep scaling, do NOT put new launch images for iphone 6/6 plus

Comment: I just need to drag and drop these new images into my project?

Comment: the logic is the same as you do currently with iphone 5 icon etc, don't you declare icons in plist, if you do not use catalog assets.

Comment: You also need to add the icon file name to "CFBundleIconFiles"

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a Launch Screen image / view?

If you're using Storyboards, try to add MainStoryboard to the Launch Screen, and make sure you've set the correct launch screens. Clean and build and see what happens.